# How to set seperate global action handler for multiple instance of eclipse form based plugin editor

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on eclipse form based editor. I have given support of handling of Undo Redo and dirty flag to my editor.Both of these feature working fine for single instances of plugin. Problem is coming when i open it with 2 or more files (2 or more instances of eclipse plugin). Now, undo redo starts working weird. They work only for instances that is opened at last.

for eg: Suppose my editor supports '.xeb' file. if i open test1.xeb and test2.xeb files one by one using with my editor. then undo redo only works for instances that is opened for test2.xeb file. If i switch back to other instances, then undo redo of first instance gets appear.

i have below entries in my editor's plugin.xml:

```
  <plugin><extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
  <editor
        class="Testeditor"
        default="true"
        extensions="xeb"
        icon="icons/sample.gif"
        id="testeditor"
        name="editor">
  </editor>
 </plugin>
```

i debugged the code and found that this weird behavior is happening due to handling of global action in wrong way.I used below code to set global action handler:

```
public void setUndoRedoActionHandlers() {

    final IActionBars actionBars = getEditorSite().getActionBars();
    actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(ActionFactory.UNDO.getId(),
            mUndoAction);
    actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(ActionFactory.REDO.getId(),
            mRedoAction);
    actionBars.updateActionBars();
}
```

i went through some links related to this issue. but couldn't understood the concept to implement this behavior.

```
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_out_what_view_or_editor_is_selected%3F
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_hook_into_global_actions,_such_as_Copy_and_Delete%3F
```

Can any one look into this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only override the setFocus() method of MultiPageEditorPart in you editor class and call the appropriate method  of setting the global action handler,like this way:

```
@Override
    public void setFocus() {
        switch (getActivePage()) {
        case 0:
            pageOne.setUndoRedoActionHandlers();
            break;
        case 1:
            pageTwo.setUndoRedoActionHandlers();
            break;
        }   
        super.setFocus();
    }
```